# Add data-ajax="false" to javascript submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I am using codeigniter with jquery and need to post a form with `data-ajax="false"`

my normal form string is:

```
<form action="/sales/new_blank_order_summary" method="post" data-ajax="false">
```

but I am using javascript to post the form so my current syntax is:

```
<SCRIPT>
function submitFunction(i) {
   if (i==1) document.sales_order_details.action=
      "/sales/new_autospread_range";
   if (i==2) document.sales_order_details.action=
      "/sales/new_previous_order_lines";
   if (i==3) document.sales_order_details.action=
      "/sales/new_blank_order_lines";
   document.sales_order_details.submit()
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

How do I add the parameter `data-ajax="false"`  to this submit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function submitFunction(i) {
    var form = document.sales_order_details;
    if (i==1) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_autospread_range?data-ajax=false";
    } else if (i==2) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_previous_order_lines?data-ajax=false";
    } else if (i==3) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_blank_order_lines?data-ajax=false";
    }
    form.submit()
}
```

or

```
function submitFunction(i) {
    var form = document.sales_order_details;
    if (i==1) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_autospread_range";
    } else if (i==2) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_previous_order_lines";
    } else if (i==3) {
        form.action = "/sales/new_blank_order_lines";
    }
    form.action += '?data-ajax=false'
    form.submit()
}
```